# How can I solve all IE CSS problems with one plugin?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, plugins

I'm having trouble about IE versions. There is different js plugins for IE problems. For example:  jquery.corner.js for corner radius. Well, Is there any plugin for all IE problems (IE6,7,8,9). Or Do we have to use different plugin for each problem?

Comment: Don't -1 a new-ish user without explaining why guys. Thats hardly helpfull. As for the answer: there are so many different problems between the different versions of browsers that there is no one-fix-for-all. You could start with ie htmlboilerplate though. (http://html5boilerplate.com/). That should atleast fix quite a heap of problems for you. There are ofcourse more "boilerplate" solutions out there with the same purpose.

Comment: Look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp) and tell me why you want to support IE6 + IE7? Just force users to update the browser. Like Google does not even support IE8 anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 1-size-fits-all solution for browser inconsistencies. Its the worst thing for web devs to deal with.

There are some things that can make it easier on you though. One of which is starting out with a good `reset css`. Google it for several options.

One place to start with is http://html5boilerplate.com/, but there are others that help.

Also writing good semantic html and working up from there helps alot to dodge the browser specific problems.